# Java IO: CharsetDecoder.decode() does not work properly on Linux

Tags: java, java-io

I've wrote small method what converts incoming String to UTF-8 encoding:

```
private String convertStringToUTF8( String pIncomingString ) throws CharacterCodingException {

        CharsetDecoder cd = Charset.availableCharsets().get("UTF-8").newDecoder( );
        CharBuffer buffer = cd.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(pIncomingString.getBytes()));

        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

This works perfectly on Windows machine, for example - 'ScÃºp' gets replaced with 'Scúp'. However, when deployed to Linux, it does not work ('ScÃºp' remains 'ScÃºp').
Do anyone know how to resolve this annoying issue on Linux?

Comment: I could be wrong but can it be that the system can't print out UTF-8 and not the actual encoding that is erroneous?

Comment: No. Application then writes to database. In one case I get 'Ãº', in another 'ú'.

Comment: UTF-8 is an encoding from characters to bytes. The notion of a UTF-8–encoded `String` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: There's no such thing as a UTF-8 `String`; there are only UTF-8 bytes.    When you call `pIncomingString.getBytes()`, you're converting the string to bytes using the platform default charset, which may or may not be UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding JVM argument -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 .

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a String is not safe to use as a sequence of bytes.  String.getBytes() is not guaranteed to return one byte per character.  Indeed, in Linux, where the default encoding is usually UTF-8, String.getBytes() will convert any characters above \u007f into multiple bytes.

In summary, when you want to store a sequence of bytes, use `byte[]`, not String.